# How did 歸 (revert, send) + 納 (give, receive, insert) compound to signify 歸納 (to deduce, summarize)?

Tags: etymology

1. Does  歸納 wrongly conflate deduction and induction, which are different reasonings. Watch [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nn3XMoPC7s).

[image]

2. Anyhow, how do 歸 and 納 semantically appertain 歸納? What semantic notions underlie 歸納? Neither 歸 nor 納 signify deduction, induction, or summarization.

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) pp 272.

[image]

*Op. cit.* p 516.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

歸 - return --> put things to where they belong

e.g. 將芭比娃娃和 G.I 乔可动人偶歸為一類 (玩偶) - Put Barbie dolls and G.I Joe action figures into one category (dolls)

納 - bring in --> bring things in the group they belong

e.g. 將廣東話和客家話納為一類 (南方方言) - bring Cantonese and Hakka into one category - (Southern dialect)

歸納 = to sum up/ to summarize

Example: 歸納以上各點得出來的結論是⋯ The conclusion drawn from summing up the above points is ...

> *Neither 歸 nor 納 signify deduction, induction, or summarization.*

- 歸 does signify deduction, when you return things to where they belong, you deduct them from the uncategorized pile
- 納 does signify induction, when you bring in things to where they belong, you induct them into the categorized pile
- As for 歸納 signify summarization, it is explained in this post